# How to count and apply a merge on missing data between two dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to fill a dataframe with missing data. I've got these two dataframes:

```
df1:

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':['11','11','11','11','22','22','43','43'], 'x': ['d1', 'd2','d3','d4','d1','d2','d1','d3'], 'b': [1, 2,3,4,5,6,7,8]})

    a   x  b
0  11  d1  1
1  11  d2  2
2  11  d3  3
3  11  d4  4
4  22  d1  5
5  22  d2  6
6  43  d1  7
7  43  d3  8

df2:

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'x': ['d1', 'd2','d3','d4']})

    x
0  d1
1  d2
2  d3
3  d4
```

I've tried doing this:

```
df1.groupby('a', as_index=False).apply(lambda d: d.merge(df2, on='x', how='right')).reset_index(drop=True)
```

But my result is:

```
      a   x    b
0    11  d1  1.0
1    11  d2  2.0
2    11  d3  3.0
3    11  d4  4.0
4    22  d1  5.0
5    22  d2  6.0
6   NaN  d3  NaN
7   NaN  d4  NaN
8   NaN  d2  NaN
9   NaN  d4  NaN
10   43  d1  7.0
11   43  d3  8.0
```

My desired output would be:

```
     a   x    b
0   11  d1  1.0
1   11  d2  2.0
2   11  d3  3.0
3   11  d4  4.0
4   22  d1  5.0
5   22  d2  6.0
6   22  d3  NaN
7   22  d4  NaN
8   43  d1  7.0
9   43  d2  NaN
10  43  d3  8.0
11  43  d4  NaN
```

Is it possible to fill the missing data represented by `NaN` in the rows that I need? This way I've got `d2` and `d4`in rows `8` and `9` when I need them in rows `10` and `11`

My dataframe has around 150-200 rows so I'm trying to keep this generic as much as I can

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For performance `groupby` with `merge` is not good idea. Better is create `MultiIndex` with all possible combinations for `a` and `x` columns and use [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df1['a'].unique(), df2['x']], names=['a','x'])
df = df1.set_index(['a','x']).reindex(mux).reset_index()
print (df)
     a   x    b
0   11  d1  1.0
1   11  d2  2.0
2   11  d3  3.0
3   11  d4  4.0
4   22  d1  5.0
5   22  d2  6.0
6   22  d3  NaN
7   22  d4  NaN
8   43  d1  7.0
9   43  d2  NaN
10  43  d3  8.0
11  43  d4  NaN
```

Then if need set `a` by missing values from `b` column and get them to end of groups by `a` use:

```
df = (df.assign(tmp = df['b'].isna())
        .sort_values(['a','tmp'])
        .assign(a = lambda x: x['a'].mask(x['b'].isna()))
        .drop('tmp', axis=1))

print (df)
      a   x    b
0    11  d1  1.0
1    11  d2  2.0
2    11  d3  3.0
3    11  d4  4.0
4    22  d1  5.0
5    22  d2  6.0
6   NaN  d3  NaN
7   NaN  d4  NaN
8    43  d1  7.0
10   43  d3  8.0
9   NaN  d2  NaN
11  NaN  d4  NaN
```

Comment: Your first answer fits perfectly: mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df1['a'].unique(), df2['x']], names=['a','x'])
df = df1.set_index(['a','x']).reindex(mux).reset_index()

Comment: can we talk on a chat to discuss a improvement on this?

Comment: @GABRIELANDRADEQUEIROZ - I think best is create new question.

Answer (score 0):

I might not fully understand the question, shouldn't the concatenation be more like:

```
      a   x    b
0    11  d1  1.0
1    11  d2  2.0
2    11  d3  3.0
3    11  d4  4.0
4    22  d1  5.0
5    22  d2  6.0
6   NaN  d3  NaN
7   NaN  d4  NaN
8    43  d1  7.0
9   NaN  d2  NaN
10   43  d3  8.0
11  NaN  d4  NaN
```

Which is what I get from your code:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':['11','11','11','11','22','22','43','43'], 'x': ['d1', 'd2','d3','d4','d1','d2','d1','d3'], 'b': [1, 2,3,4,5,6,7,8]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'x': ['d1', 'd2','d3','d4']})

print(df1.groupby('a', as_index=False).apply(lambda d: d.merge(df2, on='x', how='right')).reset_index(drop=True))
```

Result:

```
[Running] python -u "c:\MyProjects\~python\pandas\dframe.py"
      a   x    b
0    11  d1  1.0
1    11  d2  2.0
2    11  d3  3.0
3    11  d4  4.0
4    22  d1  5.0
5    22  d2  6.0
6   NaN  d3  NaN
7   NaN  d4  NaN
8    43  d1  7.0
9   NaN  d2  NaN
10   43  d3  8.0
11  NaN  d4  NaN
```